# Implementing the Huawei IAP on Android

Tags: android

does anyone try to implement the Huawei IAP(In-App Purchase) to your android app? because, I'm trying to implement it but I have a problem to the dependency.

It says `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.huawei.hms:iap:4.0.0.300`

I'm just trying if this dependency is working and skipped some of the steps on the tutorial

This is the tutorial link https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#5

Hope someone can help..

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add to build.gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
     .....
     maven {
         url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
     }
  }
```

Comment: This is the answer!